# Live Video Display Stutter Using StetchBlt to Write Bitmaps To Panel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, image-processing, live-video

The project I'm currently working on requires live AGC and display of 14 bit gray-scale video. The video is grabbed with a Teledyne Dalsa Camera Link card and processed as a pixel array on one thread where it is finally stored as a Bitmap. A second display thread constantly grabs the latest available Bitmap image and writes it to a panel using StretchBlt. The processing thread runs on average around 40hz while the display thread can re-draw the latest image at 150hz or faster. Obviously the same image is re-written multiple times before a new one becomes available, but I don't think that is an issue. The problem that is occurring is that there is some sort of stutter using this method of display. When the video camera feeding this program is slewed left or right it's not smooth and there is a bit of lag/aberration. Vertical lines in the image seem to hang slightly.

My question is, is there a way to fix this? Is there a better way to display live video? Both threads are running plenty fast enough to render video that doesn't stutter but somehow it still does graphically when compared to a 30hz unprocessed analog signal. Any input would be appreciated and I can provide more information if it will be helpful.

Thanks!

Kidron

Answer (score 0):

You can not fix this problem -  it is hardware one.

This aberration arises due to [rolling-shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter) effect on CMOS matrices.

Pictures on different matrix lines are fixed in different time moments, so upper and bottom parts of frame have temporary lag (there are left-to-right shutters too), and vertical lines become bent when camera  (or scene) moves.

Some video edit software might partially correct such distortions, but full restore is not possible.

Comment: We are using a FLIR SC6000 series imager which uses a cooled InSb detector that I believe is area scan...shouldn't be any possibility of rolling shutter there, am I correct? This only happens when it's viewed in my processing software.

Comment: I am re-drawing the display screen on a timer so I wonder if perhaps I'm accidentally creating a "rolling shutter" style effect because the timer is not waiting on a previous write to finish. When a new frame arrives it could be being drawn almost overlapping the old frame. I should probably do the draw on a "new frame ready" even instead of in a faster loop that is in no way synced to the processing thread.

Comment: I think timer approach is not very good, but doubt it could cause such effects - you draw the whole picture, not line by line, yes?. Recommended way: after grabbing a frame invalidate app window/form, in paint message handler (is something like this available in c#?) output the picture.

Comment: About SC6000 - I don't see clear specification that it uses global shutter (descriptions of some cameras emphasize when it is present). But Readout modes in data sheet include Async. Integrate While Read and Async. Integrate Then Read. Do you know about this option meaning?